# Was it double homicide?

Tags: abortion

A person is accused of two counts of murder, because the victim was a pregnant woman.

The lawyer representing the defense makes the proposal that it couldn't be two, because legally, only one death involved was human.

Assuming the accused is convicted of the murder of the woman herself, what about the second death? Is it still considered murder? Why?

Comment: Considered ethically? morally? (if so under what system) legally?  (if so under what jurusdiction)?

Answer (score 1):

This is going to vary by jurisdiction.  Under the Wisconsin [first-degree intentional homicide](http://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/document/statutes/940.01) law, it counts as two offenses, because the law explicitly says so:

> (a) Except as provided in sub. (2), whoever causes the death of
>   another human being with intent to kill that person or another is
>   guilty of a Class A felony.
>   (b) Except as provided in sub. (2),
>   whoever causes the death of an unborn child with intent to kill that
>   unborn child, kill the woman who is pregnant with that unborn child or
>   kill another is guilty of a Class A felony.

There are similar provisions in the [first-degree reckless homicide](http://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/document/statutes/940.02(1m)) law, the [second-degree intentional homicide](http://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/document/statutes/940.05(2g)) law, the [second-degree reckless homicide](http://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/document/statutes/940.06(2)) law, etc.

The National Conference of State Legislatures has a [page](http://www.ncsl.org/research/health/fetal-homicide-state-laws.aspx) which lists fetal homicide laws, and says 38 states have them.  (Although it's strange to me that they cite Wisconsin's separate [antiabortion law](http://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/document/statutes/940.04), instead of the law I cited that's literally in the homicide law.)

Comment: Many states make unlawfully terminating a pregnancy via an assault of a pregnant (whether or not the pregnant woman dies) a serious and separate felony. Most do not classify that offense as murder.