# What crime is killing a foetus without the mother's consent?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

According to US law, when a person approaches a woman who is pregnant in the third trimester, usee a knife and "takes the life of the unborn child" while the woman survives, is this crime a murder or a personal injury to the pregnant woman, or both?

Does anything change depending on the month that the pregnancy had reached?

Comment: Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/24520/3209

Comment: In nearly half of US states, the law applies at all states of gestation. As far as I know, nowhere is the law applicable only from the 7th month.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Murder is most often prosecuted by the states, not the US government, and each state greatly varies on the subject. Some states consider a fetus to be a person at any stage in its development; some require harsher punishments if the defendant knew the victim was pregnant; and some have no specific mentions of whether a fetus makes any difference in the law. You can see a great breakdown of the various laws and how they are applied to fetuses in [this per-state table](http://www.ncsl.org/research/health/fetal-homicide-state-laws.aspx).

Any federal crimes that are prosecuted by the US federal government are also subject to the [Unborn Victims of Violence Act](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unborn_Victims_of_Violence_Act) which recognizes a fetus as a victim if it is injured or killed while committing a list of federal crimes.